# Google Result Shows Archive Instead Of Title Tag

Tags: google-search

I have a problem with my review category.

My posts on other categories are shown in a normal way. I mean google shows title tags in the search result, but for the posts in review category, instead of showing title tags, it shows category and archive (course review Archives)[image]

of course, it happens when I type my title tag in the search result. for the above example, I type

> advanced price action course (review+coupon)

and the result is the above picture. but when I type mentioned title tag plus my website name:

> advanced price action course (review+coupon) offbeatforex

I can see the title tag instead of the archive version, however, the archive version still comes after that.

[image]

Does anybody know the answer? Your answer will be sedative for my burning mind :) :-D

Answer (score 1):

first off, thank you Closetnoc for your answer. I'd pretty much read and watched all those subjects before and I follow the SEO rules, however, I don't push it.

I checked them one more time, good practice again.

I don't like messing with coding stuff, so I try not to do so. a darg and drop code for example to change the color of a table is not a big deal and doesn't take too much time but I prefer not to do more.

I think google takes care of everything and we don't need to do more other than writing good content and following basic SEO rules.

anyway, I just wanted to give a quick update in case someone has the same problem.

The only thing that I did was submitting the sitemap, I thought I had done it, to the google console and requesting indexing those pages.

the problem solved

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution. I would not have thought submitting a sitemap would have done anything in this case. I will have to research and think about why it worked for future users. Cheers!!

Comment: BTW- I argue that basic SEO is all that anyone should worry about. There are enough details in just doing the basic things and I have found that basic SEO is enough. No need to get into the weeds. Just do a good job from the jump and Google will treat your website well. No-one gets the basics right for all the pages right from the jump. Simple changes to the basics can really make a huge difference when you discover them.

Answer (score 0):

Both searches are not equal.

With `advanced price action course (review+coupon)`, there is no branding signal.

With `advanced price action course (review+coupon) offbeatforex`, there is.

When you search for `advanced price action course (review+coupon)`, Google returns many sites that rank for this search.

When you search for `advanced price action course (review+coupon) offbeatforex`, Google returns your site with the two pages.

Both pages should rank for these searches. Without getting into on-page SEO too deeply, both pages are sending identical signals to Google. Which one ranks for which search is likely due to external factors such as which one was discovered first, links, how many clicks it takes from the home page to get to the page, citations, social media activity, SERP (search engine result page) performance, etc.

If you prefer one to show over the other, use a canonical tag on the page that you do not prefer to point to the page you want preferred.

[Consolidate duplicate URLs](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en)

[Specify your canonical](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html)

You would place the canonical tag in the `<head>` section of the page you do not prefer.

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/mypage/thatIdo/prefer/" />
```

If this is NOT what you want, then you need to study how to rank pages for search using on-page signals.

[On-page SEO](https://moz.com/blog/category/on-page-seo)

[On-Page Ranking Factors](https://moz.com/learn/seo/on-page-factors)

These are enough to get you started.